# Prompt the user to save the .xlsx file in a particular directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I'm using npm exceljs to export an .xlsx file. My issue is that instead of saving it to a default directory(./sor.xlsx), I want the .xlsx file to open up and let the user choose where to save the file.

Code:

```
workbook.xlsx.writeFile("./sor.xlsx") // dont want to specify the path here
.then(function(){
    console.log('xls file is written');
});
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: In stead of opening the file to let the user save it, isn't there another way to ask for the desired path? I didn't find any simple npm programs that handles this, but you could write a modal that shows one directory content at the time and let the user go back and fourth.